# How to build an object file in XCode 4?

Tags: c, xcode, xcode4

How can I build a C/C++ Object file in XCode 4? In other words, I want to do the equivalent of:

```
gcc -c main.c
```

to generate a main.o.
XCode 3.x used to have a "BSD/Object File" target type, but this seems to be absent from XCode 4.0. I've tried several target options, but XCode 4.0 seems to always try to link them.

Comment: I've tried both options mentioned below, but they don't seem to work. XCode still tries to link "Relocatable Object Files", and it tries to use "Static C Library" as an actual library (-lbla).

Answer (score 0):

In your target's settings, in the «Linking» section, you can choose the Mach-O Type.

Maybe «Relocatable Object File» is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

> …Xcode 3.x used to have a "BSD/Object File" target type, but this seems to be absent from XCode 4.0…

- New Project
- Framework & Library
- BSD C Library
- Click 'Next'
- Type= Static